# How to replace column names based on partial string match in R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a integer variable `period` that I use to make dummy columns as follows:

```
library(fastDummies)

df <- data.frame(period = c(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3))

df <- dummy_cols(df, select_columns = "period")

 period period_-1 period_-2 period_-3 period_0 period_1 period_2 period_3
     -3         0         0         1        0        0        0        0
     -2         0         1         0        0        0        0        0
     -1         1         0         0        0        0        0        0
      0         0         0         0        1        0        0        0
      1         0         0         0        0        1        0        0
      2         0         0         0        0        0        1        0
      3         0         0         0        0        0        0        1
```

I would like to replace the names of the columns for the dummies of negative and positive values of `period` to "lag" and "lead" respectively. The ideal output (with `period_0` manually renamed to `event`):

```
 period      lag1      lag2      lag3    event    lead1    lead2    lead3
     -3         0         0         1        0        0        0        0
     -2         0         1         0        0        0        0        0
     -1         1         0         0        0        0        0        0
      0         0         0         0        1        0        0        0
      1         0         0         0        0        1        0        0
      2         0         0         0        0        0        1        0
      3         0         0         0        0        0        0        1
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-`sub` will work:

```r
colnames(df) <- sub("period_-", "lag", colnames(df)) |>
  sub("period_", "lead", x = _)
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "lead0"] <- "event"
df
#   period lag1 lag2 lag3 event lead1 lead2 lead3
# 1     -3    0    0    1     0     0     0     0
# 2     -2    0    1    0     0     0     0     0
# 3     -1    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
# 4      0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0
# 5      1    0    0    0     0     1     0     0
# 6      2    0    0    0     0     0     1     0
# 7      3    0    0    0     0     0     0     1
```

With `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~
    if_else(.x == "period_0", "event",
            sub("period_", "lead", sub("period_-", "lag", .x))))
#   period lag1 lag2 lag3 event lead1 lead2 lead3
# 1     -3    0    0    1     0     0     0     0
# 2     -2    0    1    0     0     0     0     0
# 3     -1    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
# 4      0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0
# 5      1    0    0    0     0     1     0     0
# 6      2    0    0    0     0     0     1     0
# 7      3    0    0    0     0     0     0     1
```

---

Starting data

```r
df <- structure(list(period = -3:3, "period_-1" = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), "period_-2" = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), "period_-3" = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), period_0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), period_1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), period_2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), period_3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same results using stringer as well:

```
# Replace column names using stringr
colnames(df) <- str_replace_all(colnames(df), c("period_0" = "event", "period_-" = "lag", "period_" = "lead"))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think all is said with @r2evans solution.

This one is more just for fun and bring in action my favorite function `parse_number()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

x <- parse_number(colnames(df))

newcolnames <- case_when(is.na(x) ~ "period",
          x < 0 ~ paste0("lag", abs(x)),
          x > 0 ~ paste0("lead", x),
          x == 0 ~ "event")

df %>% 
  rename_with(~newcolnames)
```

```
 period lag1 lag2 lag3 event lead1 lead2 lead3
1     -3    0    0    1     0     0     0     0
2     -2    0    1    0     0     0     0     0
3     -1    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
4      0    0    0    0     1     0     0     0
5      1    0    0    0     0     1     0     0
6      2    0    0    0     0     0     1     0
7      3    0    0    0     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: Creative approach! I wonder if it'd be a little more robust (to more non-pos/neg column numbers) to replace the first arg with `is.na(x) ~ colnames(df)`

Comment: Definitely better approach!